# GDB traces automatically

Tags: gdb

If I set up a break point and if GDB hits the break points, then it shows the line of the code. If I enter <kbd>n</kbd> or next, then GDB prints out the next line of the code.

I was wondering if there is a way I can trace the actual line of code being executed through GDB.

For example, if I enter <kbd>n</kbd> or next 100 times then I will get traces of 100 lines of code. I want to do this automatically not by entering <kbd>n</kbd> or next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that collecting `next` trace like you appear to desire is exceedingly unlikely to help you debug actual problem in any realistically sized program: most of the time programs spend in loops, and executing `next` repeatedly will just give you a never-ending stream of loop repetitions.

That said, you can achieve what you want like this:

```
(gdb) shell perl -e 'print "n\n" x 100' > gdb.cmd
(gdb) source gdb.cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

put a breakpoint 100 lines from your current position and continue the execution

Comment: How will that collect a trace of next 100 lines executed?